# On the curve $xy^2 = 2a^3 , a > 0$ find all the points where the normal to the curve pass the origin.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, implicit-differentiation

On the curve $xy^2 = 2a^3 , a > 0$ find all the points where the normal to the curve pass the origin.

My idea.
Use formula for normal.
$$(y-y_0)=-\frac{1}{y'(x_0)}(x-x_0)$$
So we need $y'$. We will find it by using implicit differentiation.
$$y^2+2xyy'=0$$
$$y'=\frac{-y}{2x}$$
We know that $x=0=y$.
$$-y_0=\frac{-2x_0^2}{y_0}$$ 
$$y_0^2=2x_0^2$$
But we know that $y_0^2=\frac{2a^3}{x_0}$.
$$\frac{2a^3}{x_0}=2x_0^2$$
$$x_0^3=a^3$$ 
This is solution for $x_0$, and by supstitution we know what is $y_0$
Is my work ok?

Comment: Yes, this looks good.